# Sending user's input from JavaScript into date filter webpart

Tags: javascript, filter, date-time

I want to do date filter for one field in my external list using calendar in order to hep user input date value.

Since drop-down calendar in date filter web part doesn't work (i don't know why, when i click on it only error message is displayed), i created my own calendar view with Javascript and now can get user's input value.

But i can not send this user's value in filter box to begin search. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update calendar view so that it filter based on Query String.

From after user selects date, you should use JavaScript to form the new URL with QueryString and redirect to the same page.

http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html